# How anaconda manage python version in linux server? Can I do the same without sudo privilege?

Tags: server, python

I normally manage my python environments on my laptop with virtualenv. Hence, I can install any dependencies for each python version easily. However, I recently join a project group that work on linux server. Most people use anaconda as python version and environment manager, and they can do that with simple command that came with anaconda.

The situation is that none of us has sudo privilege, is root user, or is apt accessible, but anaconda can deal with this task. On another hand, I found on many other forums that people that doesn't use anaconda face a very troublesome problems of installing, and path managing every dependencies. Is there a comprehensive resource I can follow?

Comment: This seems like a discussion that needs to happen within your project about what resources and tools the sysadmin should provide.

Comment: @user535733 Sorry for the late reply, but my intention is to do some thing like what I answer below, i.e. install multiple pythons from source with as few admin commands as possible assuming that admin pre-install as minimal modules as possible for the most generalized solution for people with similar problems, but with slightly different in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem with all local method. It is pretty tedious, but it works for me, and this might be helpful for people in the same situation as me. I believe that anaconda do something similar, but automatically.

Assuming that the server's admin already provide basic installing modules, i.e. build-essential, wget, tar. (If not, I'm not sure, but I think one can use similar method as I will be describing.)

Now, the modules needed for python building from sources are as follow:
bzip2, gdbm, libffi, libuuid, ncurses, openssl, readline, sqlite, xz, zlib.
In fact, one can finish the python installation w/o issue if one only install zlib, libffi, and openssl. However, if one want to complete all optional modules, then every module is needed to be installed.

Finally, there is another module that is vital for visualization, e.g. for matplotlib. This module require installation of:
tcl, tk.

Furthermore, tk needs X11 module, and its friends. If the server isn't already had, then one also need the following:
inputproto, kbproto, libpthread-stubs, libX11, libXau, libxcb, pkg-config, xcb-proto, xextproto, xproto, xtrans.

After one installs all requirements, and requirements of each requirements, and so on (with each specific configure), one need to either 1. set PATH, CPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and ACLOCAL_PATH to bin, include, lib, lib/pkgconfig, share/aclocal folder of each module or 2. make symlink of all content in each file to associated location that each path variable is set to.

Then, one can install python from source with all requirements (including the optional one)

As for how to install and symlink each module and python, I want to give all credit to
[Kakeru Sato](https://noknow.info/it)

Comment: After that, one can select a version of python as their main version, and install virtualenv from source into that python binary folder.